# Why do multicolored lines keep appearing on my FEniCS plots?

Tags: matplotlib, fenics

I'm using FEniCS to solve a basic diffusion-over-time problem as a proof of concept. I am only using a single linear solver, but when I plot my function with pyplot, I get *several* multicolored lines, any one of which could represent the true function. How do I eliminate these and just see the one function?

Additionally I would note that over time, all of the function lines approach the same curve.

```
solve(a == L, u, bcs, solver_parameters=dict(linear_solver='gmres', preconditioner='ilu'))

plot(u)
```

[image: pyplot with several function lines]

Comment: `u` is probably a 2-D matrix. you should edit your example to make it runnable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

I was solving my PDE over time, with a for loop. I was telling the program to plot the solution every iteration. But telling it to *show* the solution only every five iterations. This resulted in it showing the past five solutions it had plotted all on top of one another.